# Socket.IO Timeout connect_error

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, socket.io

I'm trying to learn about socket.io and I followed along with many tutorials but can't get it to connect properly.

**Server Side: index.ts**

```
import express from "express";
import { Server } from "socket.io";
import http from "http";
import cors from "cors";


//connections
const app = express();
const server = http.createServer(app);
const io = new Server(server);

app.use(cors);

app.listen(4000, () => console.log("Server is running on port 4000"));

io.on("connection", (socket) => {
    console.log("socket connected");
});
```

**Client: index.js**

```
const io = require("socket.io-client")
var socket = io.connect("http://localhost:4000");

socket.on("connect", () => {
  console.log(socket.id); //Doesn't enter here
});

socket.on("connect_error", (err) => {
  console.log(`connect_error due to ${err.message}`); //Outputs connect_error due to timeout
});
```

Client keeps printing

```
connect_error due to timeout
```

Consider that this is my first time using socket.io.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are creating two http servers, giving one to socket.io, but never starting that server.  So, socket.io will never work because it's attached to a server instance that isn't running.

These are conflicting:

```
const server = http.createServer(app);
```

and:

```
app.listen(4000, () => console.log("Server is running on port 4000"));
```

Because each creates a new server.  Inside of `app.listen()`, it does:

```
const server = http.createServer(app);
server.listen();
return server;
```

So, remove this:

```
const server = http.createServer(app);
```

And, change from this:

```
app.listen(4000, () => console.log("Server is running on port 4000"));
```

to this:

```
const server = app.listen(4000, () => console.log("Server is running on port 4000"));
```

Then, use that ONE `server` variable for socket.io.

---

You could also do it the other way where you remove the `app.listen()` and use the `server` you already created and then just do `server.listen(...)`.  The point is that you need to create only one server instance instead of two and give that one actually running server instance to socket.io and express.

Answer (score 0):

The problem must be in your URL.
const socket = io('http://192.168.0.191:3000', {
autoConnect: false,
});

In case of react-native the URL will be your system IP address which you will get running the **ip addr** command.

inet **192.168.0.191**/24 brd 192.168.0.255 scope global dynamic noprefixroute wlp0s20f3